# Getting Bluemix Server error: "The UAA endpoint needed is disabled"

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am getting the error `The UAA endpoint needed is disabled` when i do the following using CF CLI:

1. Assigning role to user in Org
2. Assigning role to user in Space
3. Creating/ Associating user in Org programatically.

Can anyone let me know the reason for this error and how this can be resolved?

Comment: Can you share your code, and optionally let us know more about the project you have created?

Comment: I am using Java APIs setting the url as  "http://api.<subdomain>/v2/organizations/<guid>/users" and passing the username in JSON format. As suggested by the link below: https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/222/organizations/associate_user_with_the_organization_by_username.html

Comment: JSON request:

{
  "username": "<username>"
}


i am getting the following response:

{
  "code": 20005,
  "description": "The UAA endpoint needed is disabled",
  "error_code": "CF-UaaEndpointDisabled"
}

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that the commands set-org-role and set-space-role in CF CLI versions 6.14 and later are currently not working with Bluemix. In order to use these commands please make use of CF CLI 6.13

For your info, the releases and related info can be found here:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases

Comment: I am trying to associate a user with Org programmatically using APIs. I have cloudfoundry-client-lib-1.0.0.jar in my classpath. I have used v1.1.0 and v0.8 also but i still get the UAA endpoint disabled error.

Comment: The json call does currently not work, please use the following command instead:
https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/221/organizations/associate_user_with_the_organization.html

Comment: Is there a way I can associate a user with Org using username? I can do it  by providing user guid but i don't have user guid. When I try to list all users within that Org, i get CF-NotAuthorized (You are not authorized to perform the requested action) error, even though I have admin privileges and this org was created by me. please help.